# Customiser - BGColor and BGImage Display

Tags: css, wordpress

Had this working in the past but suddenly its not. Below is the structure:
Thre is a setting and control for it as well, and the background color and image settings both work individually however when I have both settings it wont work, Originally I had it working that the color always worked unless a background image was selected and that would override it but now the color works and background-image doesn't. is there a way to get this working again?

```
<footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div id="inner-footer" class="row">
        <div class="large-12">
            <div class="medium-6 large-6 columns">
                <div id="dragoncove-footer-textleft" class="float-left">
                    <?php { echo get_theme_mod( 'dragoncove_footer_textleft', 'No Copyright Information Added Yet' ); } ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="medium-6 large-6 columns">
            <div id="dragoncove-footer-textright" class="float-right">
                <?php { echo get_theme_mod( 'dragoncove_footer_textright', 'No Information Added Yet' ); } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Here is the Functions:

```
    function dragoncove_footer_customize_css() {
?>
    <style>
        <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'dragoncove_footer_textleft', 'Content Left Not Added Yet.' ); ?>
        <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'dragoncove_footer_textright', 'Content Right Not Added Yet.' ); ?>
        footer.footer {background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('dragoncove_footer_bgcolor', '');  ?>; }
        footer.footer {background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_mod('dragoncove_footer_bgimage', '')  ?>); }
        footer.footer {padding: <?php echo get_theme_mod('dragoncove_footer_padding', '');  ?>; }
        footer.footer {color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('dragoncove_footer_navfontcolor', '');  ?>; }
    </style>
<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'dragoncove_footer_customize_css');
```

Comment: Why is `<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'dragoncove_footer_textleft', 'Content Left Not Added Yet.' ); ?>` and `<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'dragoncove_footer_textright', 'Content Right Not Added Yet.' ); ?>` inside your `<style>`?

Comment: removed those from the styles now.

Answer (score 0):

found the fix. adding the ()

```
footer.footer {background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_mod('dragoncove_footer_bgimage', '()')  ?>); }
```